# "When" or "Where" when refering to scenario?

Tags: grammar, when, where

In a sentence like, "This bias may not be acceptable in all scenarios, especially **where/when** recall is important," which of where/when should be used?

Comment: I think the word should be "especially"?

Comment: I suggest rewriting (the un-given context) so that it can end along these lines - "*This bias may not be acceptable **if** recall is important,*"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> In a sentence like, "This bias may not be acceptable in all scenarios,
>   especially where/when recall is important," which of where/when should
>   be used?

Let's diagram. (partial for the sake of brevity)

This bias | may be acceptable | not | in all scenarios | especially | where/when recall is important

This is a Complex Sentence with one main (independent clause) and one subordinate (dependent clause).

Main: *This bias may not be acceptable in all scenarios* [notice that this main clause can stand alone as a complete sentence, which is why it's call an independent clause]

Dependent: *especially where/when recall is important* [the bias may not be acceptable for reasons, one in particular involves "recall" and this adverb dependent clause modifies, like an adverb, the verb phrase "may be acceptable" (negated, made negative by the adverb *not*) to show and answer "**When**?" When is it not acceptable? When it involves "recall" (whatever *recall* may pertain to). The adverb *especially* modifies the entire adverb dependent clause because the clause acts as a single part of speech, an adverb: Not just *when*, but *especially when*

**Where**. *adv*.

: act or in what place

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/where

In this sentence *when* is used as a *subordinating conjunction*.

**When**. *conj*.

:at any or every time that

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when

Plugging in the definition of **when**...

This bias may not be acceptable in all scenarios, especially *at any or every time that* recall is important.

CORRECT:

This bias may not be acceptable in all scenarios, especially ***when*** recall is important.

Comment: This answer is not very clearly written, but its conclusion (that ‘the correct option’ is _when_, not _where_) is wrong. Both _when_ and _where_ make sense and are equally valid here.

Answer (score 1):

We can use both according to the preferred context. There are three main relative adverbs  namely where, when and why.  While ' when' refers to time, 'where' refers to place, but the curious thing about them is that , as relative pronoun they both mean 'in which' or 'at which'.

'Scenario'  can suggest a situation already determined or yet to be determined. What's of prime importance is the antecedent— here, the scenario. In a determined situation it is better to use 'when' , otherwise, 'where'. In the present context, on a superfluous level, both can be used as, neither to time nor to place, 'Scenario'  directly refers.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, a scenario would be a *where*, but in informal speech, people frequenty choose *when*.

By the way, I would use *especially* in place of *specially*.  But note, the sentence doesn't make sense to me, at least without any context.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to my comment above -

*This bias may not be acceptable for scenarios in which recall is important.*

Comment: or "especially those in which" if the questioner prefers the original format